# How to identify each value in Google Sheets API on Android

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a problem in validation check.

### Problem situation

Let's suppose that there is below table which has empty cell in Google sheets.

[image: TableImage]

Each student has Empty cell(score). But, when you get these data by using Google sheets API, You cannot identify each score.

#### Code and Result (Problem situation)

```
String spreadsheetId = "Something Sheet ID."
String range = "Sheets1!A:I"
ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
```

And if you print that function's result, you can get lists like below.

```
{1, A, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90}
{2, B, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90}
{3, C, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90}
{4, D, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90}
{5, E, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90}
{6, F, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90}
{7, G, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90}
```

The problem is, when I get these data by using Google sheets API, I cannot know which score is omitted. (Of course, I could know there is missing data. Because list length is shorter than I expected.)

### Google said.

> Empty trailing rows and columns are omitted.

### What I want!?

I want to know which data is omitted or each data's index. For example, what is Student G's first 90 means?

Comment: Only trailing and empty rows or columns are omitted, not empty rows or columns bounded by data.

Answer (score 1):

That's how [Sheets API works](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/). What you can do is create a placeholder character that represents "empty cells". For example, if there's a blank cell, don't leave it empty. Instead, place a 0 value in that cell to identify it as 'empty'. Now, when you read the whole cell range, you know the cell is empty if you encounter the '0' placeholder. You get my drift.